# Does the expression "con la coda tra le gambe" always refer to a shame-driven action?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, idioms

In a casual chat, I just wrote:

> Siamo in balia del clima caldo e molto umido per tutto il mese di giugno. E sembra si faccia sempre peggio ogni anno che passa. Roba da rendere intollerabile la vita! Basta trascorrere una settimana d'estate in Giappone per farti venire voglia di tornartene **con la coda tra le gambe**! :D

I wonder if the expression "(fare qc) con la coda tra le gambe" always refers to a shame-driven action? Or can you also use it when you  have reached a point where you cannot stand something (like an uncomfortable level of humidity in this context) any longer? That is, when the *flight*-impulse is triggered by lack of patience, tenacity etc?

Comment: The expression is used to express despondency genererally after being unsuccessful. ***Avere la coda tra le gambe***: mostrarsi avvilito dopo un insuccesso. https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/avere-la-coda-tra-le-gambe - I am not sure what concept you want to express in your sencence.

Comment: I agree with Gio. Alone-zee, did you mean that going in Japan turned out to be a bad decision? This is more or less what transpires by your phrasing, almost as if to say that you championed going there, and now have to admit it was a mistake.

Comment: @Gio / DaG The main idea I want to convey here (jokingly) is that spending just a week in Japan is enough to make Europeans (who are generally not accustomed to extremely humid climates) think twice about living here. Like, it turns out to be not as good as it's cracked up to be, at least climate-wise, so you basically hightail it out of here. Perhaps matching the description "*express despondency genererally after being unsuccessful*"?

Comment: https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/con-la-coda-tra-le-gambe After reading the description on this webpage "subito un'umiliazione", I was under the impression that the expression might always revolve around a sense of shame/embarrassment/humiliation. Which prompted this question. By the way, is it less common to say "con la coda **fra** le gambe"?

Comment: Hmm.. The problem here is that *farti venir voglia di tornartene con la coda tra le gambe* is a bit of an oximoron. No one wants to feel humiliated. What about *farti tornare indietro con la coda tra le gambe*?

Comment: It's up to you, Alone-zee: if in that sentences you want to convey a sense that the travel to Japan was some of a failure of judgement and the utterer is, indeed, at least a bit ashamed of having suffered rather than enjoying it, _tornare con la goda fra le gambe_ is perfectly correct. If you/he is just upset and cross, it isn't.

Comment: @DenisNardin "Oximoron", good point!!

Answer (score 2):

*Tornare con la coda tra le gambe* means coming back from some experience ashamed of what happened, embarrassed by the result, significantly inferior to what one expected.

Carlo Lapucci's *Dizionario dei modi di dire della lingua italiana* lists it among other ones with a similar meaning:

*Partire a cavallo e tornare a piedi*
*Entrare papa in conclave e uscirne cardinale*
*Fare come i pifferi di montagna (che andarono per sonare e furono sonati)*
*Tornare a piè zoppo*
*Andare per lana e tornarsene tosi*
*Tornare con la coda fra le gambe*, ovvero *come un can frustato*
*Tornare a mani vuote*
*Tornare con le pive (trombe) nel sacco*
*Restare a bocca asciutta (a denti asciutti)*
*Restare con un palmo di naso*

So, in all cases, they do not refer, as perhaps in the Japan example, to a generic unpleasant experience, but to a humiliating one, where an outcome taken for granted was degradingly missed, and the person was actually or figuratively beaten.

Answer (score -1):

Very likely this stock sentence derives from dogs' [obviously, non-verbal :)] communication: keeping the tail between legs is possibly one of the most common and better known dogs behaviours. Largely, it means that the dog is scared, very often due to the fact that the animal has been for any reason submitted or something similar. In any case, when dogs have tails between legs it means that the animal does not feel secure.

Same goes for the sentence. You use it either to say that someone needed to do something *obtorto collo* [against their will] or because they are afraid.

I'm not 100%, but I guess that in English there is the "stock sentence". *As some people has asked, "stock sentence" means "frase fatta" - think about that as "idiom".*

Comment: The stock sentence...?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! I agree with @DaG: I don't understand what do you mean with "stock sentence". Could you please edit your post and explain it?

Comment: "stock sentence" means "frase fatta", literally. Call it "idiomatic", if you prefer.

Comment: @gbiondo: The problem was not with the phrase “stock sentence”, but with the fact that your sentence was incomplete and with empty inverted commas. I (and probably Charo too) thought that something was missing, say some stock sentence you were about to quote.

Comment: And even now, I'm a little confused about what you mean by «I'm not 100%, but I guess that in English there is the "stock sentence"». Do you mean that you suspect that in English there is an idiom analogous to “con la coda fra le gambe” but you are not sure?

Comment: I know that Google claims that *stock phrase* is a translation of the Italian *frase fatta*, but I'd rather go with something like *idiomatic expression*, or *fixed phrase*. That said, even beyond that I also find your last paragraph a bit obscure. Could you try to paraphrase it a bit?